# Select first visible cell directly beneath the header of a filtered column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select the first visible cell directly beneath the header of a filtered column.  The code I am getting is as below, but I have to problems with this code.  First, the first line of code is using the current active range of the file.  It is highly likely that this file will change and this range will not be the same.  How can I make it work for any file I would use it on?  Second, if I use a totally different file with the same column format, the first visible cell under Column J could be J210.  How can I make this work for any array of variables?

```
Sub Macro16()
'
' Macro16 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$58418").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
        "Sheets"
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(RC[1],3)"
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested but:

```
Sub Macro16()

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:="Sheets"
        If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count > 1 Then
            With .Columns(10)
                .Resize(.rows.count - 1).offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(RC[1],3)"
            End With
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This code works as well! Plus this code, I can figure out what it is actually doing with out any extra explanation.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

```
Sub FirstVisibleCell()
    With Worksheets("You Sheet Name").AutoFilter.Range
       Range("A" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You can add this to your module.  the only thing you need to change it the sheet name and range "A" to the leftmost (or any) column contained in the table

Answer (score 2):

I prefer non-destructive methods of determining whether there are visible cells to work with after a filtering operation. Since you are filling in column J with a formula, there is no guarantee that column J contains any values tat can be counted with the worksheet's [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) (SUBTOTAL does not count rows hidden by a filter) but the formula you are planning to populate into column J references column K so there must be something there.

```
Sub Macro16()
    With ActiveSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Columns(12).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Sheets"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 9)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Offset(0, 1))) Then
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(RC[1],3)"
                End If
            End With
            .Columns(12).AutoFilter Field:=1
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Fill Formula to Visible cells]

Comment: This gives me what I wanted, but can you explain what each line does. I am just a novice when it comes to macros and I am not familiar with much of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work...

```
Sub Macro16()

    Dim ARow As Long, JRow As Long, ws1 As Worksheet
    ws1 = Sheets("NAME OF SHEET WITH DATA")
    ARow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws1.Range("$A$1:$R$" & ARow).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Sheets"
    JRow = ws1.Range("J" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws1.Range("J" & JRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(RC[1],3)"
    ws1.Range("J" & JRow).FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't get this one to work.  I entered my sheet with data name, but it gives me a debug error.